# detect change to window.name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a good way to detect when the window's name has changed. It is easy enough to do with `setInterval` like this:

```
var old_name = window.name;
var check_name = function() {
    if(window.name != old_name) {
        console.log("window name changed to "+window.name);
        old_name = window.name;
    }
}
setInterval(check_name, 1000);
```

However, `setInterval` is more than a little hacky and may come with a significant (1s in this case) time delay before detecting changes. Is there any kind of event or clever bit of JS that can fire a function when the window name changes?

Thanks!
Joseph Mastey

---

EDIT:

Unfortunately, I don't have control over the code that will be changing the window name, which is in a way the entire point of the exercise. Having looked at [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie) and other posts about storing data in the window name as a way to track users, I've decided that this isn't really acceptable to me. So, I'm creating a Greasemonkey script (actually, the Chromium version of a greasemonkey script) to prevent this sort of data leakage.

As an aside, I did find some magic functionality that Chromium implements that goes a long way towards what I want. JS provides magic getters and setters that can be used like this:

```
window.__defineSetter__("name", function(nm) { console.log("intercepted window.name attempt: "+nm); });
window.__defineGetter__("name", function() { return ""; });
```

If I run this on the console, I can successfully hijack sets of the window name. However, running this code as a Chromium script (at least any variant I've tried so far) does not seem to be able to override the window behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doesn't look like there is a native event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window#Event_Handlers), so polling may be your only bet.

What piece of code updates `window.name`? You could always do...

```
window.name = 'new';
windowNameChanged();
```